# I'm making an Android IME. How do I add a "Settings" list item in the "Language & Keyboard" settings screen?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, ime, android-input-method

... like "Swype settings" in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8nP2.png).  Been searching for hours on how to do this.  Going to go insane.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Finally found it by looking at the [source code for S9](http://github.com/gilbertl/S9).

In `method.xml`, you just add the attribute `android:settingsActivity="com.package.SettingsClass"` to `<input-method>`, so the entire file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:settingsActivity="com.package.SettingsClass" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but do you have the permissions and intent filters discussed in this [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)? Particularly the optional Settings activity defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Yes, my manifest looks almost identical to the one you have linked.  Additionally, I've tried adding different <category> in <intent-filter>, but to no avail.